# Need Assistance with using continue in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to relearn python, as it has been about 5 years since I have last messed with it. using a continue in the following search program is giving me a 'continue' not properly in loop error.  Any suggestions?

```
# XML search function, 5/15/2014

import os, re

def main():

    path = 'C:/Python34/test'
    listing = os.listdir(path)
    for infile in listing:
        text = open(path + '/' + infile).read()
        match = re.search('hi', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    print ('true')
    start = match.start()
    end = re.search('bye', text).start()
    print (text[start:end])
    print ('------------------------------------')

main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is off; the `continue` is *outside* the loop.

Comment: You forgot to indent the relevant code so it is within the loop.

Comment: Indentation ***matters*** in Python.

Comment: indent `if match is None`

Comment: thanks guys, much appreciated, getting used to this after 2 years of C++ :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, avoid `continue` because it hides the logical flow of the program.

```
import os
import re

def main():
    path = r'C:\Python34\test'
    listing = os.listdir(path)
    for infile in listing:
        with open(os.path.join(path, infile)) as data:
            text = data.read()
        match = re.search('(hi.*?)bye', text, re.DOTALL)
        if match:
            print('true')
            print(match.group(1))
            print('------------------------------------')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Use `os.path.join` to combine paths. Use `with` to open files, so they are closed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
for infile in listing:
    text = open(path + '/' + infile).read()
    match = re.search('hi', text)
    if match is None:
        continue
```

You outdented this part of it. Indent those last two lines as shown above.